# scikit-learn - The execution of SVM.fit function never ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

When I call the fit function of `SVM`, its execution simply never ends and the related Python process consumes CPU too much.

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_values, y_values, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=y_values)

svm = SVC(kernel='linear')

svm.fit(x_train, y_train) # The execution never ends

y_pred = svm.predict(x_test) # The execution never reaches here
```

**Software Stack:**

```
 - Python 3.7.0
 - scikit-learn 0.20.2
```

Comment: How many observations do you have in your training set? What hardware are you using?

Comment: No issues at all when I utilize other machine learning algorithms (i.e. `Random Forest`, `Naive Bayes`, etc) with the same data. @Abramodj

Comment: Try to run it on a subset of the observations (start from `10**3`, then move to `10**4` etc...) and check at which order of magnitude it gets stuck.

Comment: Try `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` instead. It uses a different formulation for linear SVMs, and can handle larger data. Also, setting `verbose=1` may give you some hints about training progress.

Comment: @rvf Actually it works now but  the `accuracy` is calculated a lot lower than the one calculated by `WEKA` using `SMO` classifier.